# i can't save my form in database while iam saving getting error "'bool' object has no attribute '_committed'"

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

hii iam new to Django so iam working on my first blog which is articals blog so i am trying to save articles from the template using Django forms but while saving getting error 'bool' object has no attribute '_committed' iam searching for a solution but didn't find out any solution. please help me.

Models.py:

```
class post(models.Model):
author = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
title = models.CharField(max_length=20)
discription=models.CharField(default=None ,max_length=100)
text = models.TextField(max_length=2000)
image=models.ImageField(upload_to="blog/",default=True,null=True,blank=True)
created_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now())
published_date=models.DateTimeField(blank=True , null=True)



def publish(self):
    self.published_date=timezone.now()
    self.save()

def __str__(self):
    return self.title
```

forms.py:

```
from django import forms
from .models import post
class post_form(forms.ModelForm):
  class Meta:
     model=post
     fields=[
        'title','discription','text','image'
     ]
```

views.py:

```
def post_new(request,*args,**kwargs):
if request.method == 'POST':
    form=post_form(request.POST,request.FILES)
    if form.is_valid():
       p=form.save(commit=False)
       p.author=request.user
       p.published_date=timezone.now()
       p.save()
       return redirect("/post_list") 
else:
    form = post_form()
context = {
    'form': form
}
return render(request,'blog/post_new.html',context)
```

Traceback:

```
Environment:
Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/post_new

Django Version: 2.2.3
Python Version: 3.7.2
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
'blog']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']

Traceback:

File "C:\Users\lenovo\Envs\blogproject\lib\site- 
packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py" in inner
34.             response = get_response(request)

File "C:\Users\lenovo\Envs\blogproject\lib\site- 
packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
115.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, 
request)

File "C:\Users\lenovo\Envs\blogproject\lib\site- 
packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
113.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, 
**callback_kwargs)

File "C:\Users\lenovo\Desktop\blogproject\mysite\blog\views.py" in 
post_new
39.             p.save()

File "C:\Users\lenovo\Envs\blogproject\lib\site- 
packages\django\db\models\base.py" in save
741.                        force_update=force_update, 
update_fields=update_fields)

File "C:\Users\lenovo\Envs\blogproject\lib\site- 
packages\django\db\models\base.py" in save_base
779.                 force_update, using, update_fields,
File "C:\Users\lenovo\Envs\blogproject\lib\site- 
packages\django\db\models\base.py" in _save_table
870.             result = self._do_insert(cls._base_manager, using, 
fields, update_pk, raw)

File "C:\Users\lenovo\Envs\blogproject\lib\site- 
packages\django\db\models\base.py" in _do_insert
908.                                using=using, raw=raw)

File "C:\Users\lenovo\Envs\blogproject\lib\site- 
packages\django\db\models\manager.py" in manager_method
82.                 return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, 
**kwargs)

File "C:\Users\lenovo\Envs\blogproject\lib\site- 
packages\django\db\models\query.py" in _insert
1186.         return 
query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(return_id)

File "C:\Users\lenovo\Envs\blogproject\lib\site- 
packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py" in execute_sql
1334.             for sql, params in self.as_sql():

File "C:\Users\lenovo\Envs\blogproject\lib\site- 
packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py" in as_sql
1278.                 for obj in self.query.objs

File "C:\Users\lenovo\Envs\blogproject\lib\site- 
packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py" in <listcomp>
1278.                 for obj in self.query.objs

File "C:\Users\lenovo\Envs\blogproject\lib\site- 
packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py" in <listcomp>
1277.                 [self.prepare_value(field, self.pre_save_val(field, 
obj)) for field in fields]

File "C:\Users\lenovo\Envs\blogproject\lib\site- 
packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py" in pre_save_val
1228.         return field.pre_save(obj, add=True)

File "C:\Users\lenovo\Envs\blogproject\lib\site- 
packages\django\db\models\fields\files.py" in pre_save
286.         if file and not file._committed:

Exception Type: AttributeError at /post_new
Exception Value: 'bool' object has no attribute '_committed'
```

Comment: Please post the complete traceback

Comment: hiii @DanielHepper i have added complete traceback please check it once and help me how to resolve it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are seeing this particular error because of the `default=True` here:

```
class post(models.Model):
    ...
    image=models.ImageField(upload_to="blog/",default=True,null=True,blank=True)
```

From the code you posted it is not obvious why the default is used, but my guess is you either didn't select a file or the file data is not sent because your form does not have `enctype="multipart/form-data"` set.

Answer (score 0):

From what I could see there were no faults in your forms.py or views.py.

I saw that the `author` field is never set. So that will give an error since it is not nullable. So either add `null=True` to the author field or set the author in the form before saving. I think you want to go for the second option.

I also noticed 2 smaller things which could be easier. See the changes in `created_date` and `published_date`

```py
class post(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    discription=models.CharField(default=None ,max_length=100)
    text = models.TextField(max_length=2000)
    image=models.ImageField(upload_to="blog/",default=True,null=True,blank=True)
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    published_date=models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```